# Placing button beside radio button group

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the following layout in which I visualised in Microsoft Word:

[image]

where the left elements are radio button group and the blue element is a button.

In HTML, I'm able to get the following:

[image]

However, I'm having issues with the "ENROL" button as I couldn't think of a way to get it to appear beside the radio button group like the visualisation above. Would appreciate some help on this.

```css
.enrol_class {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.enrol_class ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>testform</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "test2.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "enrol_class">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type = "radio" id = "rad_1" name = "classes" class = "radio_btn">
                <label for="rad_1">Class 1</label>
            </li>
            
            <li>
                <input type = "radio" id = "rad_2" name = "classes" class = "radio_btn">
                <label for="rad_2">Class 2</label>
            </li>

            <li>
                <input type = "radio" id = "rad_3" name = "classes" class = "radio_btn">
                <label for="rad_3">Class 3</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <button type = "button" id = "enrol_btn">ENROL</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox to solve that. Just need to set your parent component as a flex-container.

```
.enrol_class {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

You can read more about flexbox:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

To build on Fillipe's answer, here's an example:

```css
.enrol_class {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.enrol_class ul {
    list-style: none;
}


#enrol_btn {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>testform</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "test2.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "enrol_class">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type = "radio" id = "rad_1" name = "classes" class = "radio_btn">
                <label for="rad_1">Class 1</label>
            </li>
            
            <li>
                <input type = "radio" id = "rad_2" name = "classes" class = "radio_btn">
                <label for="rad_2">Class 2</label>
            </li>

            <li>
                <input type = "radio" id = "rad_3" name = "classes" class = "radio_btn">
                <label for="rad_3">Class 3</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <button type = "button" id = "enrol_btn">ENROL</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you look into flex. You can add you styles as you go but for positioning check on flex. Or another alternative is css grid.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>testform</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "test2.css">
    <style>
.enrol_class { display: flex; flex-direction: row, align-items: center}

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class='enrol_class'>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type = "radio" id = "rad_1" name = "classes" class = "radio_btn">
                <label for="rad_1">Class 1</label>
            </li>
            
            <li>
                <input type = "radio" id = "rad_2" name = "classes" class = "radio_btn">
                <label for="rad_2">Class 2</label>
            </li>

            <li>
                <input type = "radio" id = "rad_3" name = "classes" class = "radio_btn">
                <label for="rad_3">Class 3</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <button type = "button" id = "enrol_btn" style='margin-left: 20px'>ENROL</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this is what you're looking for

**CSS**

```css
.enrol_class {  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.enrol_class input {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="enrol_class">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" id="rad_1" name="classes" class="radio_btn">
            <label for="rad_1">Class 1</label>
        </li>

        <li>
            <input type="radio" id="rad_2" name="classes" class="radio_btn">
            <label for="rad_2">Class 2</label>
        </li>

        <li>
            <input type="radio" id="rad_3" name="classes" class="radio_btn">
            <label for="rad_3">Class 3</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button type="button" id="enrol_btn">ENROL</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[

```css
.enrol_class {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.enrol_class ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.enrol_class button{
color: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 16px 40px;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: #4472C4;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>testform</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "test2.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "enrol_class">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type = "radio" id = "rad_1" name = "classes" class = "radio_btn">
                <label for="rad_1">Class 1</label>
            </li>
            
            <li>
                <input type = "radio" id = "rad_2" name = "classes" class = "radio_btn">
                <label for="rad_2">Class 2</label>
            </li>

            <li>
                <input type = "radio" id = "rad_3" name = "classes" class = "radio_btn">
                <label for="rad_3">Class 3</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <button type = "button" id = "enrol_btn">ENROL</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xqklz.png)You will be able to achive it through css